# ion-tabs make my project infinite load

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

A month ago, I start an Ionic project and I decided to use the blank template but after creating few pages I need to make a navigation bar on the bottom like the one who is on the tabs template.

I try to create my own `navbar` component but when I put it on the home page the app starts to load for a long time and make stop work my explorer.

Can someone tell me why this happens?

I think that another option that I have is changing the template and use the one who has the navigation by default but, can I change the template and keep all I did?

> app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import {LoginComponent} from '../components/login/login';
import { UserProvider } from '../providers/user/user';
import {HttpClientModule} from "@angular/common/http";
import {SigningUpPage} from "../pages/signingUp/signingUp";
import { MunicipalitiesProvider } from '../providers/municipalities/municipalities';
import {ViewProfilePage} from "../pages/view-profile/view-profile";
import {NavbarTabsComponent} from "../components/navbar-tabs/navbar-tabs";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    LoginComponent,
    SigningUpPage,
    ViewProfilePage,
    NavbarTabsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    SigningUpPage,
    ViewProfilePage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    UserProvider,
    MunicipalitiesProvider,
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

> home.html:

```
<login *ngIf="name == null"></login>

<page-view-profile *ngIf="name != null"></page-view-profile>

<navbar-tabs></navbar-tabs>
```

> navbar-tabs.html:

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="home" tabTitle="Inicio" tabIcon="home"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="profile" tabTitle="Perfil" tabIcon="person"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

> navbar-tabs.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {HomePage} from "../../pages/home/home";
import {ViewProfilePage} from "../../pages/view-profile/view-profile";

@Component({
  selector: 'navbar-tabs',
  templateUrl: 'navbar-tabs.html'
})
export class NavbarTabsComponent {
  home = HomePage;
  profile = ViewProfilePage;

  constructor() {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad(){
    console.log('Hello');
  }
}
```

The app is on [this repo](https://github.com/CrisKrus/prematureKids) on navbar branch.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is an infinite loop with respect to your home page and navbar-tabs component.

You are setting `HomePage` as root in app.component.ts. This will set `HomePage` in navstack and load it. This, in turn has your tabs component which is again having `HomePage` as a tab. It keeps trying to generate inner tabs for every HomePage you load.

You need to set `NavbarTabsComponent` as root in **app.component.ts** and also remove the `<navbar-tabs></navbar-tabs>` from `HomePage`.

Also add  `NavbarTabsComponent` as `entryComponent` in app.module.ts since you are setting it as root.

Comment: Thanks that's was the problem, now the first time I load the app the nav is "invisible" but can click and them appears. 
Sorry, can't vote you up for the answer do not have reputation...

Comment: or you can have the tabs section in app.html itself.. Then it would be same as the tabs template..